# What is the purpose of the secret in express-session middleware?

Tags: javascript, express, express-session

I was reading the express-session README, which says about the secret:

> This is the secret used to sign the session ID cookie. [...]
>
> Using a secret that cannot be guessed will reduce the ability to
> hijack a session to only guessing the session ID (as determined by the
> genid option).

https://github.com/expressjs/session#secret

tbh: I don't really understand that.

I thought the purpose of a secret is to be used together with the session ID as parameters to some kind of hash-function, to generate a signature (as in `hash(secret, sessionID) => signature`) and that signature is appended on the session ID-value in the cookie.

Hence, that in case someone guessed a correct session ID, it still wouldn't work because the signature wouldn't match?

What is the secret actually used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When questions like this arise, it's usually best to just go look at the source code and see how the secret is used.  This is one of the advantages of using open-source code.

In the express-session code, the secret is used to "digitally sign" the value of the cookie as you can see in the express-session code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/6a128cc5941365d0416d92760328a8e11549eb5d/index.js#L656).  This allows the session code to detect if a cookie value has been tampered with or if it's still the authentic value originally set on the server and it makes them harder to "guess" in a brute force session attack.

Upon reading the cookie value later (in the code [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/6a128cc5941365d0416d92760328a8e11549eb5d/index.js#L542)), that value is checked to see if it has been properly signed with the right secret.  If not, the cookie value is discarded (not used).

This is a means of preventing hackers from making up their own cookie values or modifying cookie values since only values that were signed with the appropriate secret will test as valid.

The process of signing also has a side benefit in that it makes the value longer and somewhat random-looking, so it obscures the underlying value making it harder to guess.  The classic example would if the underlying session id was simply a monotonically increasing number, then it would be easy to guess future or previous session values.  But, once it is signed, it no longer looks like a simple monotonically increasing number and it is not easy to guess past or future signed session values.  Though express-session uses a [24 byte uid](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/6a128cc5941365d0416d92760328a8e11549eb5d/index.js#L519) as its session id, when signing it, the value extends to much, much longer which makes it even harder to guess and find valid sessions (the signed cookie value I looked at was 80 bytes long (after some encoding).

FYI, here's a simplified discussion of "why sign the cookie?": https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/68 from the express-session github repository.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and the linked issue links to [another interesting issue](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/176).
BUT that wasn't really my question, as I thought I already pointed that purpose out. The second sentence in my quote, says that a secret will "reduce the ability to hijack a session to only guessing the session ID (as determined by the genid option)." which sounds as if the secret protects from something else and guessing the session ID is still possible. At this point I think that either my understanding of the sentence is wrong, or the docu itself.

Comment: @0xnoob - As my answer explains and the linked issue explains, the signing makes tit that much harder for an attacker to guess the session cookie.  That is "reducing the ability to hijack a session" because it's now even harder to guess what the cookie needs to be in order to access someone's session.  Is there some part of that you don't understand or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: @0xnoob - Guessing a session is still possible.  The signing makes it that much harder to guess.  FYI, there is no way to support the existing behavior of sessions (the way they work today) and make them completely impossible to guess.  So, we settle for making them so hard to guess that accomplishing anything useful by guessing is basically impractical.

Comment: @0xnoob - If the attacker steals your session cookie, then they can get access to your session.  Nothing in express-session protects from that.  But, any session of consequence should be served over https so the only place to steal the cookie is at the endpoints.  If they have access to your client computer or server computer (the endpoints), you have other (probably bigger) problems.

Comment: jfriend00 - I think I just misread the documentation, for me there is a big difference between the following to statements:
the original: "Using a secret that cannot be guessed will reduce the ability to hijack a session ___to___ only guessing the session ID (as determined by the genid option)."
and what it actually meant: "Using a secret that cannot be guessed will reduce the ability to hijack a session ___by___ only guessing the session ID (as determined by the genid option)." but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @0xnoob - I would agree that the statement in the doc is not entirely clear.  I'm just trying to write an answer based on what actually happens.

Comment: But thanks for your answer, the 2 github issues were an interesting read and it looks like [even the current maintainer doesn't really know if adds security.](https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/176#issuecomment-113948308)  
Also just reading the source code is something I will consider now more often. It was actually easier to read and understand than I thought.

Comment: they actually discussed this exact sentence [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session/pull/752#pullrequestreview-424385269) but it appears they never changed it back. I will write them a message about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224057/discussion-between-0xnoob-and-jfriend00).